# Reduce thread.sleep time for access clipboard and for SendKeys.SendWait()

Tags: c#, clipboard, sendkeys, thread-sleep

I need to apply template to existing text/html content by using hotkeys.

First i get text/html then i process this text/html to add and strip off my text/html.

I did this using clipboard and hotkeys.

```
    wait 1(){ while (Win32Api.GetOpenClipboardWindow() != IntPtr.Zero)
               {
                   Thread.Sleep(100);
               }
            }

      wait 2(){       
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            while (Win32Api.GetOpenClipboardWindow() != IntPtr.Zero);
             }
```

................................................................................

```
     Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
     sw.Start();
            wait1();
            //Save Existing Clipboard Data
            clipboardData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
            Clipboard.Clear();
            //ToDo: Try to reduce both the sleep time
            Thread.Sleep(300);
            SendKeys.SendWait("^a");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            SendKeys.SendWait("^x");
            wait2();
          //here is code to get clipboard text/html and add and stripoff 
          //text/html **newdata** is text/html after my core logic.
            wait2();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(newdata, true);
            wait2();
            SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
            wait2();
            SendKeys.SendWait("^{HOME}");
            wait1();
            Clipboard.Clear();
            wait2();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(clipboardData, true, 2, 200);
    sw.Stop();
    var time = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds; //gives above 7000ms(7sec)
```

here i am sleep thread 100ms for accessing clipboard.

and for sendWait("^a") Ctrl+A and Ctrl+X i am sleep thread 300ms and 500ms resp.

when i change/less thread sleep time then it not works well(template was not applied).
I used stopWatch to know time Elapsed then it gives 7000ms(7second).

as we manually did Ctrl+A and Ctrl+X and Ctrl+V it done fast within second or max 2sec

Is there any easiest way to reduce time or any way to code differently.

Comment: If you are doing this from the main UI thread you may want to try moving the logic to a background one instead, as I think there may be some interaction with the message loop, or else allow for message processing while you wait. How to do the latter depends on whether your app is Forms or WPF.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError my app is in winForms

Comment: Then you'll want to do `Application.DoEvents();` from within your wait loops.

Answer (score 1):

Cut code will not work if you reduce the sleep time, here is the work around to make it works by use cut send key two times one after another like given below

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^x");
SendKeys.SendWait("^x");
```

now it will cut the content to your system clipboard and rest of the code to paste using ^v send keys works fine.